# Adding percentages to stacked bar graph but struggling to apply my dataset to other pieces of code from this page

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the code I've got to produce my graph without percentages:

```
OA_comm <- OA_rare %>%  
  tax_glom(taxrank = "Phylum")  %>% 
  transform_sample_counts(function(x) {x/sum(x)} ) %>% 
  psmelt() %>%
  filter(Abundance > 0.01)   %>% 
  arrange(Phylum)


OA_comm_plot<- ggplot(OA_comm,aes(x=pH_treatment,y=Abundance,fill=Phylum))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="fill") +
  scale_y_continuous()+ 
  ylab("Relative Abundance")

OA_comm_plot
```

This is the graph it makes:
[Community composition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqkzs.png)

I'm not sure how to do the stats to make the percentages and then add them to the graph. If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)

data <-
  mpg %>%
  # just to show a subset as an example
  filter(manufacturer %in% c("audi", "volkswagen")) %>%
  # group by each stcked bar
  group_by(manufacturer, model)
data
#> # A tibble: 45 x 11
#> # Groups:   manufacturer, model [7]
#>    manufacturer model    displ  year   cyl trans   drv     cty   hwy fl    class
#>    <chr>        <chr>    <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>   <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 audi         a4         1.8  1999     4 auto(l… f        18    29 p     comp…
#>  2 audi         a4         1.8  1999     4 manual… f        21    29 p     comp…
#>  3 audi         a4         2    2008     4 manual… f        20    31 p     comp…
#>  4 audi         a4         2    2008     4 auto(a… f        21    30 p     comp…
#>  5 audi         a4         2.8  1999     6 auto(l… f        16    26 p     comp…
#>  6 audi         a4         2.8  1999     6 manual… f        18    26 p     comp…
#>  7 audi         a4         3.1  2008     6 auto(a… f        18    27 p     comp…
#>  8 audi         a4 quat…   1.8  1999     4 manual… 4        18    26 p     comp…
#>  9 audi         a4 quat…   1.8  1999     4 auto(l… 4        16    25 p     comp…
#> 10 audi         a4 quat…   2    2008     4 manual… 4        20    28 p     comp…
#> # … with 35 more rows

tibble() %>%
  ggplot(aes(manufacturer, displ, fill = model)) +
  geom_col(
    data = data %>% summarise(displ = mean(displ))
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = data %>% summarise(displ = mean(displ), sum = sum(displ)) %>% mutate(frac = sum / sum(sum)) %>% ungroup(),
    mapping = aes(label = percent(frac)),
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5)
  )
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'manufacturer'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'manufacturer'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>